# Compare date present in different rows of a data-frame using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date-comparison

I am reading a document from mongodb and a csv file and merging them both to retrieve duplicate records. I have the following code. Now I want to compare the date (LastUpdate) between these records and return a row which has a latest date. can somebody help?

Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from pymongo import MongoClient
from functools import reduce

try: 
    client = MongoClient() 
    print("Connected successfully!!!") 
except:   
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB") 

# database 
db = client.conn
collection = db.contactReg

df = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))
print(df)

df1 = df[df.duplicated(['name'], keep = False)]
print(df1)

# reading the csv file
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\swetha1\Desktop\rules.csv')
print(df2)

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on="source")
print(df3)
print(df3.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
Connected successfully!!!
data from mongo
    LastUpdate                       _id    name  nameId  source sourceId
0  10-Oct-2018  5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39f8  swetha   123.0   Blore       10
1  11-Oct-2018  5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39f9  swetha   123.0   Mlore       11
2   9-Oct-2018  5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39fa  swathi   124.0   Mlore       11

fetching duplicates
    LastUpdate                       _id    name  nameId  source sourceId
0  10-Oct-2018  5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39f8  swetha   123.0  Blore       10
1  11-Oct-2018  5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39f9  swetha   123.0  Mlore       11

reading CSV file
   source  P.weight  N.weight  Tolerance(days)  Durability(Days)
0  Blore       100      -100                0                 0
1  Mlore       200      -200               30               365

merging
    LastUpdate                       _id    name  nameId  source sourceId  
P.weight  N.weight  Tolerance(days)  Durability(Days)
0  10-Oct-2018  5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39f8  swetha   123.0  Blore       10       
100      -100                0                 0
1  11-Oct-2018  5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39f9  swetha   123.0  Mlore       11       
200      -200               30               365
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df3['LastUpdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['LastUpdate'])
df4 = df3[df3['LastUpdate'] == df3['LastUpdate'].max()]
```

Or use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) :

```
df3['LastUpdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['LastUpdate'])
df4 = df3.loc[[df3['LastUpdate'].idxmax()]]
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Extending the above question if i want to compare based on some conditions then how to do it? for eg: " if LastUpdate(Blore) older than Lastupdate(Mlore) then -100 in the N.weight. if LastUpdate(Mlore) older than the other then -200 in N.weight. can u  help plz?

Comment: @swethareddy - Not sure if understand, for second need `max_Mlore_val = df3.loc[(df3['source'] == 'Mlore'), 'LastUpdate'].max()`
    
    `df3['N.weight'] = np.where(df3['LastUpdate'] > max_Mlore_val, -200, df3['N.weight'] )` ?